# "URI is not registered (Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Schemas and DTDs)" how to fix

Tags: android, kotlin

i am using Kotlin in android studio
i'm new to coding so i don't know how to fix this, i think there is something wrong with the XML file where the error message i get is with the 2 urls, it says "URI is not registered (Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Schemas and DTDs)".

How do i fix this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEfT7.png)

I checked under the settings but i don't see how to register the URI.

Comment: It looks like you copy pasted some xml in there without deleting the old header.  It should only have one <?xml> tag and one <selector> tag

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.